# i am still getiing it "UnexpectedValueException Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController]."

Tags: php, laravel

i check everything and everything is fine, i put the right namespace but why the error is giving me double App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController?

**web.php**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController;
Route::get('company', CompanyController::class, 'index')->company;
```

**companycontroller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Job;

 use App\Traits\UploadTrait;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Models\Company;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use Validator;
```

i put at the right folder too but it is not working

Comment: The namespace is `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Job`, you use `use App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController`. What is `->company` supposed to do?

Comment: manage to open the form but when i click button to submit i get Target class [CompanyController] does not exist.

Comment: @kins.updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use name method to create route name and pass controller and index inside array
Your namepsace should be

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Job\CompanyController;

Route::get('company', [CompanyController::class, 'index'])->name("company");
```

You can read more about routing in laravel official documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing

Answer (score 0):

if you submit a form , you need a Post Route::post('company', [CompanyController::class, 'index'])->name("company.store");